# Python3 - KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, attributes

I have a code as per follow:

```
for mth in month:
    mdfm = mdf[mdf['month']==mth]
    mdfm['exceeded'] = ""
    mdfm['percent'] = (mdfm['windspeed'] / mdfm.groupby('month')['windspeed'].transform('sum'))
    mdfm1 = mdfm
    mdfm1.loc[(mdfm1.windspeed>20), 'exceeded'] = 1033
    mdfm1 = mdfm1.groupby('exceeded').sum()
    dfwi.loc[1033, mth] = np.float64(mdfm1.loc[1033, 'percent'])
    mdfm1 = mdfm
    mdfm1.loc[(mdfm1.windspeed>22), 'exceeded'] = 1034
    mdfm1 = mdfm1.groupby('exceeded').sum()
    dfwi.loc[1034, mth] = np.float64(mdfm1.loc[1034, 'percent'])
    mdfm1 = mdfm
    mdfm1.loc[(mdfm1.windspeed>22), 'exceeded'] = 1035
    mdfm1 = mdfm1.groupby('exceeded').sum()
    dfwi.loc[1035, mth] = np.float64(mdfm1.loc[1035, 'percent'])
```

Everything should go well but I got an error like this:

```
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\921390\Programs\Scripts\Process_era5_file.py", line 554, in <module>
    dfwi.loc[1034, mth] = np.float64(mdfm1.loc[1034, 'percent'])
  File "C:\Users\921390\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 925, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\921390\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1100, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "C:\Users\921390\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 838, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "C:\Users\921390\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1164, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\921390\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1113, in _get_label
    return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\921390\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3776, in xs
    loc = index.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\921390\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 1034
```

I don't understand why at other rows the code run well but the row that has attribute "1034". Appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I added full track error

Comment: Is condition `mdfm1.loc[(mdfm1.windspeed>22), 'exceeded'] = 1035` correct? Because same like `mdfm1.loc[(mdfm1.windspeed>22), 'exceeded'] = 1034`

Comment: Yes. Other rows run ok but the row including '1034'. If I delete that row, the error will occur in another row. I have another code with the same structure and it run very well. I don't know why this code gets error like this. What a headache!

Comment: From your comment, so if you delete 1034 row,  the error pops up in the 1035 row?  what does your sample look like?

Comment: The purpose of this code is adding the value from dataframe to spreadsheet number by number based on its coordinate (column and row). And yes, if I delete 1034 row, the error will pop up in the 1035 row. So on for 1033, 1032, etc (the error will occur at the last row).

Answer (score 0):

One potential source of errors and unstable behaviour in your code are those lines:

```
mdfm1 = mdfm
mdfm1.loc[(mdfm1.windspeed>20), 'exceeded'] = 1033
```

The thing is, assignment of a dataframe to a new name does not create a copy of this dataframe. So when you modify `mdfm1`, you also modify the initial `mdfm` object.

If you want to create a true copy of `mdfm`, you should do it like this:
`mdfm1 = mdfm.copy()`. This would prevent changes in `mdfm1` propagating back to `mdfm`. Hope this was useful :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it seems not different without ".copy()", the error still pops up at the last row. Is there any other ideas?

Comment: "The thing is, assignment of a dataframe to a new name does not create a copy of this dataframe (pandas goes for a shallow copy of the underlying object)." It is **not** a shallow copy, it's not any kind of copy. There is only one object.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, could you please explain a bit more? I did not really get you all. Does problem here due to my assigning dataframe to a new name?